# ionic routing issue, shows blank page in link

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I started building ionic app but i have a serious problem with routing! I have added a button but it links to a blank page and not showing the content of that page!

I have 3 files:

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    $stateProvider.state('page', {
  url: '/templates/page',
  views: {
    home: {
      templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
       controller: 'PageCtrl'
    }
  }
})

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

and tab-chats.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Chats">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{chat.face}}">
        <h2>{{chat.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{chat.lastText}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
          Delete
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
     <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/templates/page">Scientific Facts</a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I assume you don't have a `<ion-nav-view name="home"> </ion-nav-view>` defined anywhere in code.

```
 .state('page', {
    url: '/templates/page',
    templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
    controller: 'PageCtrl'
   }
 }
```

if you have defined it. then it should be

```
.state('page', {
  url: '/templates/page',
  views: {
    'home': {       // it should be in quotes.
      templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
      controller: 'PageCtrl'
   }
}
```

I know you are new and all, but please first go through the DOCS. You need to understand routing completely to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I met once this issue and it can be very tough to find out what's the problem with the white-screen.

But follow this check-list and you may get it solved:

1) In your index.html, check that you are not including any inexistent or wrong JS script. (The script src tag).

2) Double check the order of your JS files when they are loading in your index.html.

3) Remove the semicolon (;) at the end of each state URL configuration.

4) Make sure to use a single-quote when you are doing:

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/users');
```

5) Don't hesitate to comment the code in your controller related to the white-screen URL.

6) Finally, try to replace the URL that you want to route by another one that you can see when you are testing your app. For example if you get a white-screen when you try to route to /users but you can see /home view. replace the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise by /home and see if it displays when you are testing on a real device or emulator. By doing this, you can already know that it is either the view or the controller of the white-screen routing which contains a possible error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to a Syntax error or a wrong logic somewhere in your code. You need to debug the JavaScript code to find out where it is. Here is how you can do it:

1) Let's say for instance you get the white-screen-of-death when you are routing to /user URL.

2) Comment all the code of the controller related to the /user view. You should be able to get rid of the white-screen.

3) Uncomment your code and start to add few alert() dialog after each code line in your controller-function scope and search where it block to the white-screen.

For example, I got the white-screen-of-death because in my view I was doing a ng-repeat on a Array which is dynamically created by one of my function controller and cannot load it before the fetching process was done. As soon as that I figured out this issue I start to use ng-init to load the Array and then iterate with ng-repeat. Everything is now fixed!

As I said the white-screen you got is more about a logic error happening somewhere in your code. Hope it does help.